# Speed for getting lines between specific line numbers

Tags: file, unix

I used the following command for getting lines between specific line numbers in a file:

```
sed -n '100000,200000p' file1.xml > file2.xml
```

It took quite a while. Is there a faster way?

Comment: Don't bother searching another command line, you have the right one =)

Comment: consider editing your question to include the output of `time sed '...' f > f2` . Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your file has a lot more records than the limit you set, 200000, then you spend time reading the records you do not want.

You can quit out of sed with the q command, and avoid reading many lines you don't want.

```
sed -n '100000,200000p; 200001q' file1.xml > file2.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try the `split` command.

`split -l 100000 file1.xml file2`

Then you will get multiple files with postfix aa, ab, etc.  You will be interested in the one postfixed with `ab`.